# Approximate Diagonally Dominant Matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization, numerical-methods, algorithms

I have a following symmetric block matrix.
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} \\
A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23} \\
A_{31} & A_{32} & A_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

I want to find another approximate block diagonally dominant matrix $D$ in a cone of positive definite matrices such that
\begin{align}
\min_{D \in S_{++}}\; & \|A - D\|^2_F \\
\text{st:}\; & \|D^{-1}_{11}D_{12}\| + \|D^{-1}_{11}D_{13}\| \leq 1 \\
             & \|D^{-1}_{22}D_{21}\| + \|D^{-1}_{22}D_{23}\| \leq 1 \\
             & \|D^{-1}_{33}D_{31}\| + \|D^{-1}_{33}D_{32}\| \leq 1. \\  
\end{align}

Copying diagonal blocks, making them positive-definite, and zeroing off-diagonal blocks is a feasible solution. In general it is not clear on how to impose these constraints of the form
\begin{equation}
\|D^{-1}_{ii}D_{ij}\| \leq \theta_{ij}.
\end{equation}

Any norm in the constraints that makes the problem tractable is acceptable. I am wondering if there is an algorithm or a procedure that allows me to find an approximate block diagonally dominant matrix.